# Getting error when running after simulator task in my Matlab workflow

Tags: matlab

When i am running start simulator in my Matlab workflow i am getting below error.

**The mex compiler '' is not supported for simulation builds. Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported compiler.**

**Scenario** : In my matlab project i have *.mdl files. After generated diagram fro that mdl files, i clicked on one of my scope diagram then i am getting above error

Please let me know can i need any compilers, if so tell me i will do accordingly.

Any suggestions/methods to follow get sort out from this error.

Thanks in advance for you great valuable replies.

Comment: What version of Matlab? Almost always this question is crucial when debugging Mex compile issues.

Comment: R2009a running on windows 8 64 bit os.. but is now working fine in windows 7 32 bit os.

Comment: sometimes on Windows it's a matter of getting the right MS runtime libraries to go with that version of Matlab

Comment: So what i need to do solve this error @paisanco

Comment: Thought you said it was working on a 32-bit system? For R2009a on Windows 8, you may need to try an older version of MS compiler, see http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/release2009a/win64.html

Comment: Also, Windows 8 is not supported for R2009a, see http://uk.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/release2009a/